# How Change psql Versions?

Tags: postgresql, binary

My system is looking at `usr/bin/psql` and I need to use `/usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql` but I'm not sure how to change it.  I don't feel like I should be deleting or renaming the first one.  How can I get my system to use the other one with minimal change on my filesystem?  Do I use an `alias` in my `.bash_profile`?

BTW first version is 9.2.24 and second one is 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias is fine. You can just create an alias that includes all of the connection info for the database something like.

```
alias mydb='/usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U myuser mydatabase'
```

That way you don't have to retype everything. And you still have access to 9.2 version of psql in your shell if you need it. (note that the above assumes that the postgresql-10 database server is listening on 5433 rather than 5432 which is the standard port )

Answer (score 1):

The question does not mention the Linux distribution, but the `/usr/pgsql-10/bin` path suggests RHEL-based. Because it is possible to have multiple versions of PostgreSQL installed on a single system, the *alternatives* program is used in RHEL-based distros for managing symbolic links from `/usr/bin` to utilities of a particular PostgreSQL version in `/usr/pgsql-*/bin`. Debian-based distros use the similar *update-alternatives* program.

List all installed alternatives:

```bash
$ alternatives --list
pgsql-pg_config         auto    /usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_config
pgsql-createdb          auto    /usr/pgsql-14/bin/createdb
...
pgsql-psql              auto    /usr/pgsql-14/bin/psql
...
```

List alternatives for a specific program:

```bash
$ alternatives --display pgsql-psql
pgsql-psql - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/pgsql-14/bin/psql
/usr/pgsql-14/bin/psql - priority 1400
Current `best' version is /usr/pgsql-14/bin/psql.
```

Select a different alternative:

```bash
$ sudo alternatives --config pgsql-psql

There is 1 program that provides 'pgsql-psql'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/pgsql-14/bin/psql

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `/usr/pgsql-10/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`.  You can do this by adding the following to the end of your shell's initialisation file (e.g. `~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`):

```
PATH=/usr/psql-10/bin:$PATH
```

The same could be done in any script that needs to use `psql` from `/usr/psql-10/bin` rather than from the default path (modifying the `PATH` in a script should happen *early* in the script).

Modifying `PATH` is the most common way to change the "personality" of a script or shell session on systems with alternative implementations of various utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a `postgresql.x64_86` or similar installed.  I took that out and the correct `psql` was automatically chosen as $PATH was already correct.